# How to use the equals operator with a variable?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How can I use `==` with a variable?

Example:

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp: datetime, method: string, value: real) [ 
'2020-01-01 12:00:00','A',1,
'2020-01-01 12:30:00','B',2
];
let method = 'A';
T | where method == ???
```

Using `method == method` returns the whole table.

Comment: The obvious answer would be not to reuses a column name for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead - `_method` instead of `method`, to prevent the names from colliding:

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp: datetime, method: string, value: real) [ 
'2020-01-01 12:00:00','A',1,
'2020-01-01 12:30:00','B',2
];
let _method = 'A';
T | where method == _method
```